# How to active and deactivate function on check

Tags: javascript, canvas, checkbox

I wish to run 2 function: 1 if check box checked another if the check box is not.  I can not seem to activate the Wave() function at all.  but the draw() function is as required.  It is just to activate or deactivate on check box checked or otherwise.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var PI2 = Math.PI*2; //place the circle on canvas
var cx = document.getElementById('xpos');
var cy = document.getElementById('ypos');
var fuzz = document.getElementById('blur');
var intensity = document.getElementById('intense');

//Gets the initial values for wave form
  var sinCheckBox = document.getElementById('sin');
  var sinInput = document.getElementById('sin-f');
  var periodInput = document.getElementById('period');
  var ampInput = document.getElementById('amps');
  var yPosInput = document.getElementById('Y-pos');

  var isDrawSin;
  var sinFrequency;
  var period;
  var amp;
  var yPosition;
  var xPosition;
  var factor;

  draw();

function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('sin').checked) {
            wave();
        } else {
            draw();
        }
    }

function draw(){
  example = intensity.value/10;
  //console.log("the intensity = " + example);

  ctx.globalAlpha= example;
  ctx.fillStyle='rgba(25, 255, 50, 0.8)';
  ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(25, 255, 50, 1)';
  ctx.shadowBlur = fuzz.value; 
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx.value,cy.value,3,0,PI2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  drawFrame();
  drawCross();

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

  function wave() {
    resize();
    setParameters();
    drawFrame();
    drawCross();
    drawWave();
    requestAnimationFrame(wave);
  }
```

I would like the draw() function to be active at the start but when the user checks the 'sinCheckBox = document.getElementById('sin')' to switch to the wave() function and stop the draw() function.  And vice versa.

Thanks

Comment: I think it may be necessary to see where you are calling `validate`, and the html associated with this code. A fiddle would be even better.

Comment: Why dont you use Jquery onclick function?

Comment: something like $( "#sin" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling validate from  anywhere, 
You might want to call validate instead of draw. Which will decide which function to use